# Viewing a PDF file with Vue.Js

Tags: pdf, vue.js

I want to view a PDF file when a button is clicked with Vue.js.

```
let pdfWindow = window.open("")
  pdfWindow.document.write("<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64, " + encodeURI("URL HERE").
```

I have tried using iframe,  it works with Google but does not work with IE.

How can I solve this issue.

Comment: Why are you using `encodeURI` on what appears to be a base64-encoded string? Also, which version of IE?

Comment: It is one of the requirements to use a base64 string.IE version 10.